# how can we use open layer map on windows form

Tags: c#, .net, openlayers, desktop-application

i am working on open layer map worked that is related to driver tracking, making shortest path, poly line and polygons  so my question is that how can i use open layer map API on Windows Form .net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the WebBrowser control and the Navigate method to load your HTML-Script.

Comment: so you are saying that there is a method that i followed to integrate open layer map on desktop application in windows form ??

Comment: Yes, that´s right. Here is a working example (NavTools - OpenSeaMap): https://lechterbeck.wixsite.com/nauticalsoftware